# In Java, how to convert from 2017-03-22T08:57:13-04:00 to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS z

Tags: java, date, datetime

My understanding is:
2017-03-22T08:57:13-04:00 is the current time and offset w.r.t GMT 
and yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS z is the GMT time.

I didnt find any java util to quickly convert this from one format to another. Do we need to use the string util to convert?

My preference would be to use the Java Date or Calendar Util to do the same.

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 1):

I think with what you're asking you need to take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` might be of help here. Also `DateTimeFormatter` might be an option. The former accepts a pattern in the constructor and can then be used to convert a `java.util.Date` via `new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(date)`.

DateTimeFormatter is part of the new Date API of Java8 and works similarly but with the new types like `java.time.LocalDateTime`, i.e. `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(LocalDateTime.now())`.

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered many times already.

The old `Date` and `Calendar` classes are an awful mess, poorly designed, flawed, confusing, and troublesome. They are now legacy, supplanted by the modern java.time classes.

Your format is standard ISO 8601 format. These standard formats are used by default in the java.time classes.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-03-22T08:57:13-04:00" )
              .toInstant()
              .toString()
              .replace( "T" , " " )
```

> 2017-03-22 12:57:13Z